# Cannot connect Micromax MMX354G datacard in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, drivers, internet, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I am using Micromax MMX354G datacard. I want to connect it to my Ubuntu PC, which is a 64 bit PC having Ubuntu 14.04 installed in it.
The datacard comes with the linux drivers "MIMN0_D301D_linux_05.251013.354G_131025.tar.gz".
I have extracted the driver and installed with the command

`sudo tar -xvf MIMN0_D301D_linux_05.251013.354G_131025.tar.gz`

All the file get extracted along with the file named install.sh and uninstall.sh. I have tried `./install.sh`
I get this in my terminal

```
root@vvdnlt208-Vostro-3446:/home/vvdnlt208/Desktop/mmx/mmx# ./install.sh 
Version=05.251013.354G
Date=2013-10-25
Vendor=Micromax
Model=TERMOD0077
HW=HW2.0
Description:
this is connection manger, you can use it to dial to internet.
usage:
1. sudo 3g_connect.sh ttyUSB0
continue to install(yes/no)?[yes]yes
get device info...
Mass Storage Vendor=0x2020
Mass Storage Product=0x0002
Vendor=0x2020
Product=0x4010
check os support...
Linux release version:Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS \n \l

[OK]
check driver support...[OK]
install usb serial driver...modprobe: FATAL: Module usbserial is in use.
[OK]
udev rules file...[OK]
ppp config...[OK]
APN and dial script...[OK]
main app...[OK]
disable modem-manager service...[OK]
disable modem-manager service...[OK]
Installation Done!!
---------------------------
Version=05.251013.354G
Date=2013-10-25
Vendor=Micromax
Model=TERMOD0077
HW=HW2.0
Description:
this is connection manger, you can use it to dial to internet.
usage:
1. sudo 3g_connect.sh ttyUSB0
---------------------------
```

After that I inserted my datacard in my USB port. When I give the command

```
root@vvdnlt208-Vostro-3446:/home/vvdnlt208/Desktop/mmx/mmx# sudo 3g_connect.sh ttyUSB0
ttyUSB0 is not exist! exit 1.
```

Please help me to connect my datacard.

Comment: Also make sure usb-modem is detected? (post output of `lsusb` and next step is `nmcli dev list`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to connect to the Internet using the datacard and nothing else (such as making calls using the custom software your datacard manufacturer has provided), you just need to create a new mobile broadband connection for which you probably don't need to install those drivers.

Your data card should show up a usually within a minute of plugging in. Follow the following steps:

1. Click the network manager icon and you should see Mobile Broadband.
2. Once you see that, it means that your data card has been detected. Click Edit Connections.
3. In the Network Connections dialog, click on the + button to add a new connection.
4. Choose your Connection type as Mobile Broadband.
5. Click next and choose your country.
6. Click next and choose your operator.

Finish and you should see your connection in Network Manager. Click on it to connect to the network.

Answer (score 0):

http://micromax-mmx-310g.blogspot.in/

Here is how you do it.
Saki 3G works with just about any modem.

Here is a video too

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3f_LWz4WFQ